# new Date(UTCstrings), convert an UTCStrings to other timezone (not local)

Tags: javascript, datetime

I know how to use new Date(UTCStrings) to local timezone.

But now, the question is how to convert an UTCString to other timezone (not local).

**e.g.**

The UTCString is '1338480000000'. 
My local timezone is UTC+4.
I want to convert the date(UTCString) to UTC+9.

How can I do it?

Appreciate for your help!

**Update**

Thanks for BalaKrishnan's help.

I follow BalaKrishnan's key points maked a simple function. Hopefully, this will help others.

```
function utcToOtherTimezone(utcString, timezone){
    var isoDt = new Date(utcString), // do this to convert it to iso time: 
    dt = isoDt.addMinutes( isoDt.getTimezoneOffset() + (timezone * 60) );

    return dt.toLocaleDateString() + ' ' +　dt.toLocaleTimeString();
}

$('#dtime').html(utcToOtherTimezone(1341282169000, +8));​
```

And don't forget to add [datejs](http://datejs.com)

Online testing example http://jsfiddle.net/ysjia/FWbZ8/. Enjoy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a Date object from the UTCString as follows:
var utcString = 1338480000000;
// This will however be in local time, not iso time.
var isoDt = new Date(utcString);
// do this to convert it to iso time:
isoDt.addMinutes( isoDt.getTimezoneOffset()
 );
// addMinutes is an API from [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/).
Now the isoDt object has it's date value the same as the UTC date, to which you can add the necessary offset +9 or whatever.

Refer to this jquery faq that discusses this:
http://jqfaq.com/how-to-parse-a-date-string-disregarding-time-zones/